# Fetch a selected row in Zend Framework

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, fetch

I know how to Fetch all the results from the DB
What i want to do is to fetch a selected row.
 Can anyone give me a sample code.

```
public function getAllAddresses()
    {
        $dbTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
        $result = $dbTable->fetchAll();

        $addresses = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {

        $address = new Application_Model_User();
        $address->setuserId($row->userId)
            ->setuserName($row->userName)
            ->setaddressLine1($row->addressLine1)
            ->setaddressLine2($row->addressLine2)
            ->setaddressLine3($row->addressLine3)
            ->settelephone($row->telephone);

        $addresses[$row->userId] = $address;
    }

    return $addresses;
}
```

How can I do the fetch..

This is my Controller calls to the fetchAll

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        $addressMap = new Application_Model_UserMapper();
        $addresses = $addressMap->getAllAddresses();

        $this->view->addresses = $addresses;
    }
```

How can I call to the fetch method?

This is my view

```
<?php if (isset($this->addresses)) : ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Town</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
        foreach ($this->addresses as $userId => $address) {
            $trow = '<tr>';
            $s = $address->getuserId();
            $trow .= '<td>'. $address->getuserId() .'</td>';
            $trow .= '<td>'. $address->getuserName() .'</td>';
            $trow .= '<td>'. $address->getaddressLine1() .'</td>';
            $trow .= '<td>'. $address->getaddressLine2() .'</td>';
            $trow .= '<td>'. $address->getaddressLine3() .'</td>';
            $trow .= '<td>'. $address->gettelephone() .'</td>';
            $trow .= '<td><a href="Index?id='. $s .'">Edit</a></td>';
            $trow .= '</tr>';

            print $trow;
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>Address not found</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm very new to Zend and MVC architecture.
Any help would behighly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have complete documentation at
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html

you need to call the: `fetchRow()` method instead of `fetchAll()`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say You want to fetch a row with column name 'id' and `id = 5` from User Table. `$id = 5`

```
$userObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
$userRow = $userObj->fetchRow('id = '.$id);
```

Now you can access User Columns as

```
 echo $userRow->columnName;
```

Comment: -1 because recommending unsafe parameter insertion method. You should always escape your parameters. Even for simplest examples.